# Select records with few unique columns while choosing not null value over another column in priority

Tags: sql, oracle, unique, tablefilter

I would like to query a table by getting records unique to field1 and field2 while selecting the row with field4 to have some value rather than null in priority.

e.g.  in original table

```
field1  field2  field3  field4
  1       B       A     (null) 
  1       B       A       2   
  2       C       A       3   
  2       D       A     (null)
  3       D       F       3   
  2       C       A       3
```

And what I wish to get from output query is like:

```
field1  field2  field3  field4
  1       B       A       2   
  2       C       A       3   
  2       D       A     (null)
  3       D       F       3
```

Is there any efficient way of SQL table joinning technique / filtering to achieve this? Thanks

P/S - to avoid confusion, the purpose of having distinct of field1 and field2 only is because field3 can be having different values that the chosen row will be based on those row which field4 is not null in priority

e.g.

```
field1  field2  field3  field4
  1       B       A     (null)   
  1       B       C       2       <- this will be the chosen one
```

Comment: is field3 also part of the key, or do you simply want to select the value of field3 that happens to correspond? E.g. what happens if an additional row has values `2, D, X, 1`?

Comment: hi, just refer to the P/S explanation that I have just added. Yes, for `2, D, X, 1` , this will be chosen rather than that of existing `2, D, A, (null)` in the table as those row with not null will be in priority. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this:

you Just need to group by the first 3 fields and take the MAX() of filed4

```
select "field1","field2","field3",max("field4")
from Table1
group by "field1","field2","field3"
order by "field1"
```

## [SQL fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5aebe/5)

**EDIT:**

If you want **only field1 and field2** as part of grouping then try this:

```
select "field1","field2","field3","field4"
from(
select "field1","field2","field3","field4",
        row_number() 
        over(partition by "field1","field2" order by "field4" desc) as rn
from Table1)A
where A.rn=1
```

## [SQL Fiddle Demo 2](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5aebe/17)

Comment: Why is field3 included in the group by clause? The questioner wanted to be distinct only on field1 and field2.

Comment: I like the elegant solution in your first query. I would have only removed field3 from the group by and add a max(field3) to the select clause. Field 3 will not be random in that case.

Comment: @Hari that will not reflect the source data. Think at `1       B       A  3 ` and `1       B       C     1`. Using max(field3) will result `1       B       C   3` which not exists in the source.

Comment: @Hari: That will not work as Florin Ghita says ... see this demo http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7444a/1

Comment: You are right, I missed the fact that he wants to get original records not aggregated columns.

Answer (score 1):

You may use max, but must be sure that you choose the right field3. This will do that:

```
select field1, 
   field2 , 
   max(field3) keep (dense_rank first order by field4 desc) as field3, 
   max(field4)
from Table1
group by field1, field2 ,field3,
order by field1, field2
```